# Keyboard Shortcuts for TextMate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, keyboard, command, textmate

How do I get the keyboard shortcuts to work for Rails? I'm trying to insert ERb's like `<%= %>` and `<% %>` and the commands should be <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> but it doesn't work. I have the document type set to Ruby on Rails.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you are working in and ERB template they you should have it set to "HTML (Rails)".  Does that make a difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd> to display the `<%= %>` and `<% %>` you should set the template to HTML (Rails).

Comment: Thanks! I was in the Ruby on Rails mode, not HTML (Rails -- that fixed it.

Comment: Any reason the shortcut doesn't work on the application.html.erb template?  Works on all the other pages for me?